# Calculationg field values on page load in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to learn jquery making simple applications for my website based on examples found on the Internet.
It's a simple multiplication of 3 fields with a result showing in the forth input field.
In html the 3 fields have pre-set values.

Question: What makes the result value being calculated on page load without triggering it with keyup events. I found two approaches and only the second one calculates value on page load.

```
    $(':input').bind('keypress keydown keyup change',function(){
var qt = parseFloat($('#qt').val(),10),
    a = parseFloat($('#a').val(),10),
    b = parseFloat($('#b').val(),10);
// var v = '';
if (a && b && qt){
    v = a*b*qt; 
    $('#ans').val(Math.round(a*b*qt*100)/100);
}
//  $('#ans').val(v.toString());
});
```

Second example that works even on page load:

```
var calcpvc = function() {
var qt = parseFloat($('#qt').val(),10),
    a = parseFloat($('#a').val(),10),
    b = parseFloat($('#b').val(),10);
//var v = '';
if (a && b && qt){
    v = a*b*qt; 
    $('#ans').val(Math.round(a*b*qt*100)/100);
}
 //  $('#ans').val(v.toString());
};
$(':input').keyup(calcpvc).change(calcpvc).change();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I've fully understood what you're asking, but I think you're wondering why the second example works on load?

In that case it's because the function is attached to the `change` and `keyup` event of the elements, and then a `change` event is manually triggered.

Comment: So where exactly is the bit that makes the difference? Both options are sensitive on 'change' as well. I am guessing the below line forces the calculation on load but the translation of the line is not clear to me, could you comment on that:     $(':input').keyup(calcpvc).change(calcpvc).change();

Comment: The `keyup(calcpvc)` and `change(calcpvc)` are the event handlers. They are specifying the `calcpvc` function should be run when those events occur. Finally, the `change()` is making a change event happen, to call the `calcpvc` function on first load.